# Mostrar o total de registros

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, php-7

Fala Pessoal, estou desenvolvendo um sistema para videoconferências e neste deverá constar um Dashboard com algumas informações, como o total de videoconferências do dia atual, do próximo dia e a quantidade de videoconferências VIP.

Para mostrar o total de videoconferências VIP eu estou utilizando seguinte código:

```
    $dataDoDia = date('Y/m/d');
    $sqlVideo2 = "SELECT * FROM videoconferencias WHERE dia = '$dataDoDia' ORDER BY dia, horaInicio"; 
    $resultadoVideo2 = mysqli_query($connect, $sqlVideo2);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($resultadoVideo2) > 0) {

   while($dadosVideo2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoVideo2)) {   

        $vip2 = $dadosVideo2['vip'];

        $contVip = 0;      
        while ($vip2 === 'SIM') {
            $contVip ++;
        }   

        echo $contVip;                      
    }
}
```

Os dados vindos do banco são mostrados corretamente, porém o problema é que no wilhe ele está entrando em Loop infinito. 
Alguém sabe onde possa estar errado ?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problema é que você esta chamando um `while()` dentro de outro e que no segundo você define a condição como `$vip2=="SIM"`, como o `$vip2` que foi definido nessa volta do loop é de fato "SIM" ele vai criar um loop infinito, porque a condição nunca vai mudar, e não vai conseguir encerrar para continuar o primeiro `while()`:.

Tenta fazer assim, e o `echo` tem q estar fora do `while()`, se não vai imprimir a cada resultado, 1, 2, 3, etc.

Outra questão é o `$countVip` estar dentro do while, toda vez que ele voltar o loop `$countVip` se torna `0`, por isso acredito que essa a forma para obter o total:

```
$contVip = 0;  
while($dadosVideo2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoVideo2)) {   
    $vip2 = $dadosVideo2['vip'];     
    if($vip2 === 'SIM') {
        $contVip ++;
    }                   
}
echo $contVip;
```

Comment: Brother, deu certo aqui! Não tinha me atendado a esta questão da lógica de um while dentro do outro. Muito obrigado pela força.

Comment: Eu quem agradeço por poder ajudar, as vezes a gnt se perde em meio aos códigos mesmo HAUEHAUEAH

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma é alterar a sua `query` para trazer os dados prontos por dia, fazendo a verificação se é `VIP` ou não:

```
SELECT dia,
       COUNT(1) AS total,
       COUNT(CASE vip WHEN 'SIM' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS vip
  FROM videoconferencias vc
 WHERE dia BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())
 GROUP BY dia, horaInicio
```

Comment: Brother, também deu certo aqui! Valeu pela foça!